# Several doubts and questions related with definitions on Leibniz algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, nonassociative-algebras

Here are my questions for a (left) Leibniz ${\mathbb{F}}$-algebra $L$ and $M$ a Leibniz module:

1. In $L$ when you define the *Leibniz Kernel* as $\mathfrak{I}≔_{\mathbb{F}}\{[,]  :∈L\}$, can you also write $\mathfrak{I}≔\bigoplus_{∈L} \mathbb{F}[,]$ or $\mathfrak{I}≔\sum_{∈L} \mathbb{F}[,]$?
2. $()$ the associative (unital) $\mathbb{F}$-algebra of all endomorphisms
   of the $\mathbb{F}$-vector space $M$ is the same that general linear algebra
   $()$?
3. What is the usual definition of *extension* for $L$ a Leibniz algebra? And for *central extension*? (is it something related with a exact sequence?)
4. In the property "$I⊂L$ a *minimal* ideal then $I$ is an irreducible    Leibniz module", what "minimal" means here?
5. When you say "the nilradical $N$ of $L$ remains invariant under all automorphism of the Leibniz algebra" it means that is equivalent to say "for $\phi : L \to L$ any Leibniz morphism we get $\phi(N)=N$
6. What is the *standard Lie algebra* of a Leibniz algebra?
7. What means "a Leibniz algebra $L$ acts *nilpotently* on a module $M$"?
8. My definitions are: $L$ *simple* if $[L,L]\neq \mathfrak{I}$ and its unique ideals are $\{0\},\mathfrak{I},L$, and $L$ is *semisimple* if $(L)=\mathfrak{I}$. In the literature there are different definitions for simple and semisimple Leibniz algebras. Examples of this different definitions (and references)?

Sorry for post all the questions at same time, but I think they're short for dedicate one message to each one!

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Yes, you are right, too many questions! :) How many have you tried to search so far yourself? With which questions did you have problems searching for it? What is your source of the names, e.g., like *standard Lie algebra*? Is it not explained at your source?

Comment: Hi Dietrich, all questions arose reading papers, and they suppose the reader knows the basic concepts, so I can't precise more. I tried to find answers, but for example, I never found what is clearly an extension of a (Leibniz) algebra. For the standard Lie algebra, I know (for a paper) that it is used in "On Engel's theorem for Leibniz algebras" (D.Barnes) and "Jacobson's refinement of Engel's theorem for Leibniz algebras" (L.Bosko; A.Hedges; J.Hird; N.Schwartz; K.Stagg), but I can't access to them, and I'd like to understand the concept. So, please, any support would be appreciate, sincerely

Comment: I haven't seen *standard Lie algebra* of a Leibniz algebra. Could you give me at least the context? I would "guess" that you just impose skew-symmetry of the Leibniz algebra to obtain a Lie algebra from it. But there must be also *non-standard* Lie algebras attached to it, according to your suggestion. Please clarify it.

Comment: I haven't seen standard Lie algebra either. Context: to prove the Engel's theorem for Leibniz algebras. Some authors use it (mentioned in previous post). Do you know the answer for the another questions?